# htaccess rewrite in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This may be very noob question, but I am relatively new to web development and have googled a lot but could not found anything like mine.  I have a simple htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^stores/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ stores/profile.php?sid=$1
```

this works just fine like I want it

> e.g stores/profile.php?sid=12 is rewritten into
>
> stores/12/store-seo-name

and in the stores sub directory,I have a page that displays details of a product listed by each store which takes two params (store_id & product_id)
I want to rewrite it like this

> item_view.php?sid=12&p_id=35 to
>
> item/12/35/product-seo-name

I tried a lot of methods but I could not get it to work, and it gives me 404 error when I add htaccess file in the stores sub directory.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^item/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/product-seo-name$ /item_view.php?sid=$1&p_id=$2 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Thank you @thickguru. It worked when I wrote the full path like root/stores/item_view.php?sid=$1&p_id=$2